# Bash autocomplete for different directories

Tags: linux, macos, bash, script, autocomplete

I've played with bash autocomplete now for a while, but couldn't find a solution for my problem. I have a project directory with subfolders like this:

- projects/ruby/project1
- projects/ruby/project2
- projects/rails/project3
- projects/html/project4

Now I want to have a command, call it `cdproject` where I can `cd` in any subfolder within my projects dir and subdirs. And this command should provide a autocomplete feature where I can type `cdproject pr --> TAB TAB` and then get a list like `ruby/project1`, `ruby/project2`, `rails/project3`...

My problem is how to handle the subdirs. The programm `cdproject` looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
```

The `cdproject-autocompletion.bash` looks like this

```
_cdproject()
{
  local cur prev opts
  COMPREPLY=()
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
  prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
  opts=$(ls ~/Dropbox/projects)
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
  return 0
}
complete -o default -o nospace -F _o  o
```

And inside my `.bash_profile` I've sourced the `cdproject-autocompletion.bash` with

`source ~/cdproject-autocompletion.bash`

So anyone an idea, how to achieve this? Maybe the `opts` should return the subdir structure `ruby/project1` but then the autocompletion should only work on the last part, the actual project name. And I have no idea how this is possible.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question directly, but something you can look into for changing directories quickly is: https://github.com/rupa/z

Comment: What is the behavior you are currently getting? Does it work as is without sub dirs?

Comment: It now works for one folder, because my script just does a ``cd ~/Dropbox/projects/$1``. But I can't figure out how to include the subdirectories, so that I can directly switch into one subdir. Every project has a different name, maybe thats important

Comment: Would you consider simply renaming the folders to 1project, 2project etc? That's what I'd do :P

Comment: The question is old, but here is an update: For now, I use the Z Shell (zsh) along with oh-my-zsh and the plugin z. It provides a pretty good autocomplete feature. See here https://github.com/rupa/z, https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 5):

Reading deep into the question, you are looking for smoother ways to navigate the file tree from the command line.

Option 1:  Use `CDPATH`

E.g.,  `CDPATH=".:~:~/projects/ruby:~/projects/rail:~/projects/html"`
<sup>†</sup>

Note: some people find it useful to include **`..`** in `CDPATH`.

Unfortunately `CDPATH` doesn't
(always)<sup>‡</sup> support autocompletion.  There are ways to extend bash to do this.  Google with terms "CDPATH" and "autocompletion".

Admittedly this is a bit clunky. 
If there is a small set of parent directories you use, this isn't too bad.

You may have better success with `dirs`, `pushd`, and `popd`. These take some time to get the hang of. Note that `pushd` and `popd` can take a numeric parameter.

Also:
`cd -` returns you to the previous directory. Repeating the command toggles between the two most recent directories.
____________
<sup>†</sup> A lot of documents (including man pages) show **`.`**
(dot; i.e., the current directory) as a component in `CDPATH`.  However,
at least some shells seem to act as though `CDPATH` ends with **`:.`**,
so, if you say `cd foo`, you will get `./foo` unless some other parent directory listed in your `CDPATH` contains a `foo`.  YMMV.

<sup>‡</sup> Editor's note: Cygwin seems
to support `CDPATH` autocomplete out-of-the-box
(running bash version "4.1.17(9)-release").

Answer (score 1):

This seems ridiculously complex, but it's the solution I came up with:

```
function gcd {
  cd $HOME/git/firefly/$1
}

function _gcdcomplete()
{
  local cmd curb cur opts

  # base dir
  git=$HOME/git/firefly/

  # last arg so far
  cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

  # dirname-esque, but makes "xyz/" => "xyz/" not "."
  curb=$(echo $cur | sed 's,[^/]*$,,')

  # get list of directories (use commened out line for dirs and files)
  # append '/' to directories
  # cmd="find $git$curb -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf %p/\n , -type f -print "
  cmd="find $git$curb -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf %p/\n "

  # remove base dir from list and remove extra trailing /s
  opts=$($cmd | sed s:$git:: | sed s://*$:/:)

  # generate list of completions
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
  return 0;
}
complete -o nospace -F _gcdcomplete gcd
```